# Recommendations for a BitTorrent client that's not uTorrent

Tags: bittorrent

I used to really like uTorrent. It was, and still is light (both in terms of download size and memory footprint), fast, and easy to use. However, I've been turned off by their increasing tendency to do scammy things (like have the browser toolbar option checked by default, and the like), so I'd like to switch away.

Hence this question. If uTorrent was out of the question, which BitTorrent client would you recommend for Windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this Hive Five from Lifehacker:

> [Five Best BitTorrent Applications](http://lifehacker.com/5051416/five-best-bittorrent-applications)

In the list, the only two for Windows besides uTorrent are

- [Vuze](http://www.vuze.com/)
- [Deluge](http://deluge-torrent.org/).

Also, this may be worth checking out:

> [Comparison of BitTorrent clients - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_BitTorrent_clients)

Comment: I ended up going with Deluge. It seemed to be the simplest client, and reminded me of what uTorrent used to be like.

Answer (score 2):

Vuze (ex-Azureus).

Actually, it is written in Java and multi-platform, but it has a nice interface and is very powerful.

Answer (score 1):

Why not stick to a version of uTorrent that you like? You can get old versions here:

http://www.oldversion.com/uTorrent.html